# Find a linear fractional transformation that maps a line onto a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, linear-fractional-transformation

Find a linear fractional transformation that maps $Re(z) = 1/2$ onto the circle $|w-4i| = 4$

My first attempt tries to map this through simple intuitive transformation. I am starting with a vertical line crossing $z = 1/2$ transforming this to the center $T(z) = z - 1/2$ I can now inverse it to get a circle:

$$T(z) = \frac{2}{2z-1}$$

Since the circle has radius 2, and is two units upwards I can then get:

$$T(z) = \frac{4}{2z-1} + 4i$$

However, this is not equal to the suggested answer of $w = 4i - 4 + 4/z$. Does this type of intuition work for simply mappings? Could someone point out the flaw in logic?

Comment: The issue is that if you start with a vertical line through $(0,0)$ you will get a vertical line, not a circle. $0+ib\to-i/b$

Comment: The transformation $T(z)$ maps the line onto ${\rm Re z}=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation $w=\frac1z$ transforms the line $Re(z)=\frac12$ into the circle centred at $1$ with radius $1$.

You may wish to check this for yourself.

Follow this with a translation, so that the transformation $w=\frac1z-1$ will transform the line $Re(z)=\frac12$ into the circle centred at the origin with radius $1$.

Fiollow this with an enlargement of factor $4$, so that the transformation $w=4(\frac1z-1)$ will transform the line $Re(z)=\frac12$ into the circle centred at the origin with radius $4$.

Finally do another translation so the centre of the circle is moved to $4i$.

Therefore the complete transformation is $$w=4(\frac1z-1)+4i=4i-4+\frac4z$$